# Cambiar el el Método de un Datatable JQuery de GET a POST en Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

El problema que presento usando GET en la Tabla es que al exceder un cierto número de columnas salta un error de ajax y no permite paginar y hacer busquedas:

**DataTables warning: table id=TablaDatos - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7**

Estuve leyendo varios artículos que dicen que esto ocurre porque excede el número de caracteres permitidos por GET y la solución es cambiarlo por POST pero he intentado varias formas y no logro implementarlo con POST

Mi vista es la Siguiente:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="camaras">
  <!-- Tabla de Datos -->
  <div class="box-body">  
    <div class="row">  
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table id="TablaDatos" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover dataTable dt-responsive nowrap" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
              <th>Código de la Cámara</th>
              <th>Descripción de la Cámara</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Razón Social</th>
              <th>Tipo</th>
              <th>Sector</th>
              <th>Estado</th>
              <th>Municipio</th>
              <th>Parroquia</th>
              <th>Dirección</th>
              <th>Cédula</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Apellido</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Cargo</th>
              <th>Acciones</th>
            </thead>                    
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.Tabla de Datos -->
</div>
```

El Codigo Javascript para el Datatable:

```
var table = $('#TablaDatos').DataTable({
        language:
        {
          url: "{{asset('bower_components/datatables.net-bs/spanish.json')}}"
        },
        paging    : false,
        ordering  : true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        scrollY   : '25vh',
        scrollCollapse: true,
        columnDefs: 
        [ 
            {orderable: false,searchable: false}
        ],
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        rowId     : 'CAM_CODIGO',
        dom       : "<'row'<'col-sm-4'B><'col-sm-4'><'col-sm-4'f>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
        buttons   :
        [
            {extend: "copy",className: "btn-sm"},
            {extend: "csv",className: "btn-sm"},
            {extend: "excelHtml5",className: "btn-sm"},
            {extend: "pdfHtml5",className: "btn-sm"},
            {extend: "print",className: "btn-sm"},
            {text: 'Refresh',
                action: function () {
                    table.ajax.reload();
                },
                className: "btn-sm"
            },
    ],
    responsive : true,
        ajax      :
        {
            url   :"{{route('buscador.getdata')}}",
            type  :"GET"
        },
        deferRender: true,

        columns   :
        [
            {data: 'CAM_CODIGO', name:'CAM_CODIGO', id:'CAM_CODIGO', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'CAM_ALIAS', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'CAM_EMAIL' , className: 'sel'},
            {data:'CAM_DESCRI', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'TIP_DESCRI', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'SEC_DESCRI', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'EDO_DESCRI', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'MUN_DESCRI', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'PAR_DESCRI', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'CAM_DIRECC', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'CAM_CEDREP', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'CAM_NOMREP', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'CAM_APEREP', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'CAM_EMAREP', className: 'sel'},
            {data:'CAR_DESCRI', className: 'sel'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false, className: 'sel' }
        ],
    });
```

El Controlador:

```
public function getdata()
{
    $camara = DB::table('dpcamaras');
    return Datatables::of($camara)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($camara)
            {
                return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info fa fa-pencil editcam" id="'.$camara->CAM_CODIGO.'"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-close delcam" id="'.$camara->CAM_CODIGO.'"></a>';
            })
            ->make(true);

}
```

La Ruta:

```
Route::get('camara/buscador/getdata','BuscadorController@getdata')->name('buscador.getdata');
```

Mi pregunta es como migro este DataTable de GET a POST y no salte error por el numero de columnas. Con 4 a 5 funciona pero más de 5 da error con AJAX.

¿Alguna Sugerencia que me ayude a solucionar el problema?

Comment: Puede que esto te ayude.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544807/json-object-max-size

Comment: mi duda es con respecto al controlador

Comment: que necesito cambiar en el controlador para que acepte el POST

Comment: igualmente que parametros adicionales debo agregar en el DataTable

Comment: si únicamente es para hacer que el controlador acepte la llamada a esa url por post, tienes que cambiar get por post en la declaración de la ruta: `Route::post('cama...`

Comment: Igual siento que el problema lo tienes con la data máxima que aceptas...

Comment: si eso ya lo hice

Comment: ajax      :{
         url   :"{{route('buscador.getdata')}}",
            type  :"GET"
        },

Comment: ajax      :
    {
        url   :"{{route('buscador.getdata')}}",
        type  :"POST"
    },

    Route::post('camara/buscador/getdata','BuscadorController@getdata')->name('buscador.getdata');

Comment: pero falta todavia algo en el controlador para que ejecute el POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

luego de tanto buscar logre dar con la solución del error. Para enviar el metodo **POST** había que enviar con la data el **Token** generado para que **AJAX** pudiera procesar la consulta de la Tabla

```
ajax      :
{
    url   :"{{route('buscador.getdata')}}",
    type  :"POST",
    data  : {_token: "{{csrf_token()}}"}
},
```

Muchas gracias a todos por la Ayuda prestada.

Answer (score 0):

Modifique el Controlador de esta manera

```
public function getdata(Request $request)
{
    $camara = DB::table('dpcamaras');
    return Datatables::of($camara)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($camara)
            {
                return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info fa fa-pencil editcam" id="'.$camara->CAM_CODIGO.'"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-close delcam" id="'.$camara->CAM_CODIGO.'"></a>';
            })
            ->make(true);

}
```

y la Ruta:

```
Route::post('camara/buscador/getdata','BuscadorController@getdata')->name('buscador.getdata');
```

Pero aun no resuelvo el Problema. Da Error
**419 unknown status**

```
{message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…}
exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"
file: "vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php"
line: 203
message: ""
trace: [{,…},…]
```

Comment: necesito ayuda para poder resolver este problema, llevo el día tratando que funcione

Comment: con esto estas respondiendo tu duda?

Comment: Con la Respuesta de Abajo ya me permite procesar búsquedas sin importar la cantidad de información y de columnas tenga la tabla

Comment: entonces por favor solo deja la publicación que es la respuesta final, para que tu la aceptes y la comunidad te la podamos calificar; de este modo los usuarios que consulten sabrán que respuesta es la buena